# SQL - INNODB vs MyISAM vs Aria

Tags: mariadb, innodb, myisam

I wonder if anyone can tell me about InnoDB vs MyISAM vs Aria (specifically Aria which is a little newer than the others)

- Which one is faster in reads?
- Which one is faster in writes?
- Which one has transactions?
- Which one is more secure and safe (I mean not having or having less data-loss)?

Thanks

Comment: Since aria engine is not available in mysql, removed the mysql tag.

Comment: Btw, is mariadb documentation enough on this matter? https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/storage-engine-choice-aria/

Comment: I added mysql because they are related to each other somehow. So anybody searches the questions with tag 'mysql' to answer, will find this question too. Thanks for the documentation. I had seen that but it didn't satisfy. I need a really detailed info about these engines. @Shadow

Comment: Mariadb is a fork of mysql, therefore lot of questions and answers are cross applicable between the two products. However, this one is not. Regarding the info you are looking for: read / write - if you are not happy with the general statements in the documentation, then I'm sorry, but you need to do your own benchmark. Support transaction: that's easiy to look up in the documentation. So, the crash safety is the only real question there, since some configuration options may affect this.

Comment: And for that see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62837/using-aria-vs-innodb-vs-myisam

Answer (score 2):

Wrong questions. Instead ask "fast enough for my application", etc.

Don't even include `MyISAM` in the list; it is going away, does not have transactions, and can suffer data loss in crashes.

Pick InnoDB.  Period.  Full Stop.

Don't dwell on this question; move on to the next question.

Comment: 2 years later i see this post and i do NOT agree to this
i use a mix between innoDB and MyISAM and guess what, only the MyISAM files are recovered and i lost every single InnoDB because of a corrupt file on all my snapshots ( it really does not like live snapshots )

Comment: @PowerChaos It teaches you to not trust _any_ technology and make backups frequently. Who knows what will fail next?